# Downgrade PHP 5.5 to 5.4 (CentOS REMI Repo)

Tags: php, centos6, downgrade, ioncube

I have installed a LEMP stack by following this guide http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2011/install-nginx-php-fpm-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/

I now have the latest version of PHP v5.5. I then proceeded to setup my website/scripts and one of the requirement was **ionCube** Loader (some of my scripts are paid/encoded scripts).

So, I ran the ioncube installer wizard, only to find they don't support php 5.5 yet...

[image]

I now need to downgrade my PHP to `5.4`... how can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstall 5.5: `yum erase $packagenames` where $packagenames is a space separated list of the php packages that were installed with yum on the tutorial.

`yum erase php-common php-fpm`.  Likely it'll tell you it needs to uninstall other packages due to php being a dependency for them.  Fine.

Install 5.4.  Follow the same instructions on that tutorial but leave 'remi-php55' out of the last command in section 3.

Answer (score 0):

after you erase the packages, you can install php 5.4 from source!  this way you have complete control over whats compiled in, and can always have the latest version, in theory free of vulnerabilities.

on centos 6.x, here is my basic compile

> yum -y install libxml2-devel openssl-devel bzip2-devel curl-devel libjpeg-devel libvpx-devel libpng-devel libXpm-devel freetype-devel gmp-devel libicu-devel gcc-c++ postgresql-devel libxslt-devel ImageMagick-devel libgearman-devel libuuid-devel nginx
>
> ./configure  --enable-fpm --with-zlib --enable-exif --with-mysql --enable-embedded-mysqli --enable-mysqlnd --with-pcre-regex --with-openssl --with-xsl --enable-zip --enable-gd-native-ttf --with-curl --enable-sockets --with-gmp --enable-bcmath --enable-intl --with-mhash --prefix=/opt/php --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib64 --with-vpx-dir=/usr/lib64 --with-gd --with-freetype-dir= --with-bz2 --with-pdo-mysql --enable-mbstring --enable-ftp && make && make install

(be aware, i purposely install in /opt/php, so you may need to adjust your paths)

after that, you may need a few pecl mods... like imagemagick...  just down the pecl tarball and:

> cd /root/imagick-3.1.0RC2 && phpize && ./configure && make && make install

then you can tune your php.ini to load extensions as needed...